# Browser can't run <script src = 'some.js'></script> embedding in an html in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: javascript

In Ubuntu terminal, I try to use Firefox to open an HTML named `page1.html`, having `<script src = 'some.js'></script>` embeded.

`Node.js` is available on Ubuntu . The content of `some.js` is shown as below.

```
function add(a,b){
    return a + b
}
console.log(add(4,6))
```

To test it in Ubuntu terminal, I run : `node some.js` , it gives result of 10.

But, no result when I run: `firefox page1.html`.

Anyone knows how to resolve it?

Many thanks.

Comment: Did you check in browser console?

Comment: Could you please show your "page1.html" code?